# Send variable from JQuery to Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I try to send a variable via jquery to an bootstrap modal. First my jquery script.

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.test_uebergabe').click(function(){
                var idgroups = $(this).attr("id");
                console.log(idgroups);
                document.getElementById('modal-header').innerHTML=idgroups;
                $('#dataModal').modal("show");
            });
        });
 </script>
```

Here is my html part, where I need to variable in the body text.

```
    <div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    Überschrift
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Body...!
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    Footer...!
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What I must change to get the variable idgroups in the modal body?

Thank you

Comment: I don't see any element with the id of `modal-header` but there is an element with that exact class. maybe this will work for you `document.getElementsByClassName("modal-body").innerHTML = idgroups`

Comment: Oh yes, that's true. I fixed it but how can i echo this variable in html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code :)

```
$(document).on('click', '.test_uebergabe', function () {
    var idgroups = $(this).attr("id");
    $('.modal-header').html(idgroups );
    $('#dataModal').modal({ show: true });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change  `$('.test_uebergabe').click(function(){`

to  `$(document).on('click', '.test_uebergabe', function() {`

`click()` will only bind to the elements event only if it is in the DOM,

`$(document).on('click'` will bind to the element event also if its not in the DOM

Comment: I changed it but I don't get the variable into my modal-body. It is empty. Do I have to change something in that modal?

Comment: Try to append the div inner html just after the bootstrap modal has been shown. So you only need to swapp the last two lines of code. I hope it helps you.

Comment: you are trying to get `modal-header` using `getElementById` when `modal-header` is a class, are you doing the same with `modal-body`?